# How do I reconnect my ceiling light fixture with 3 sets of cables and a 4-way connector?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, light-fixture

I took my ceiling light down but forgot to take a photo before I removed the cables.

Can anyone help me with wiring back up the light fixture?

There are 3 sets of cables with 2 sets each with 1x neutral (black), 1x live (red) and 1x earth (green/yellow). The last cable which I believe is connected to the light switch has only 2 cables - 1x live (red) and 1x neutral (black).

I believe the 2 sets of the same cables (3 cables) were connected together. I don't know how the 4-way connector is used though.

Photo of the cables

[image]

Photo of the light fixture with an additional 4-way cable connector

[image]

Comment: have you ever done something like this? what tols do you have for electricity ? meter, probe ?

Comment: What country are you in? Light fitting is 250V and uses US colours, ceiling wiring appears to use pre-2006 UK colours, but no oversleeving for switched live.

Comment: It looks like Australian to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess based on UK practice, as we don't know your country or wiring code:

1. Red wires are connected together in extra terminal block.  In one 3-core cable this is your incoming live or line conductor (in pre-2006 colours), the other twisted 3-core cable leaves the fitting to go to the next light.  The 2-core red takes the live away to the switch.
2. This makes the black wire in the two core pair your switched live, ie it's live when the wall switch is on.  In the UK we'd over-sleeve that with red or brown to make that clear
3. Switched live goes into the live of the light fitting - in US terms that's 'hot' and is the black wire going into the bulb
4. Twisted black wires (incoming and outgoing neutrals) go to the neutral of the light fitting - that's the white wire
5. Green and yellow twisted wires (earth or ground) go to light fitting terminal with green and yellow wire

But if this isn't UK or something is uncertain, I'd be wanting to use a meter to confirm the wiring layout before starting.

[Details](https://flameport.com/electric/lighting_circuits/lighting_ceiling_rose_other_colours.cs4) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnpV781c6Sw):
[image: Old colours looped wiring]